# s3fs library unable to be imported in python

Tags: python, python-s3fs

I get this error when trying to import *s3fs* in *Python* 3.10.2 in *Windows*:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'is_valid_ipv6_endpoint_url' from 'botocore.endpoint'`

I found [this question](https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/2187) in *Github* that advises using `pip install urllib3==1.25.10`. I did it but the exception persists.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should update botocore version to 1.23.24 and aiobotocore version to 2.1.2.

https://githubhot.com/repo/aio-libs/aiobotocore/issues/925